# How can a player in a PbP D&D 5e game ensure the health and fun of that game?

Tags: dnd-5e, online-roleplaying, play-by-post

I recently found [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/292/are-there-any-tricks-to-a-successful-play-by-post-play-by-e-mail-game) which has a lot of good advice for things that a game-master can do to ensure that the game is successful and fun for everyone involved. However, it doesn't say anything about what a *player* should be doing.

So, **what tricks are there for a *player* to use to ensure the health and fun of a Play-by-Post game of D&D 5e?**

Answer (score 13):

This is probably more straightforward advice than you're looking for, but my primary strategy is to give the DM everything he needs in one post, or at least as much as I can with the information I have.

At the most basic level this means providing both attack and damage dice, whether or not I know that the attack will hit, but this also extends into other actions. At the table, you can have a quick back and forth with the DM while you decide on your actions. In a PbP, such a thing can take days.

So, instead of narrowing the options and then declaring what you're going to do, cover a wider range of actions. Example:

> I'll attempt to stealth out from behind the rock (Stealth roll: 1d20+5=13).
>
> IF I haven't been detected by the orc holding the hostage, I'll try to kill him from behind with a Sneak Attack (Attack: 1d20+6=14; Damage: 1d6+1d6+1d4=12)
>
> IF the I am detected by the orc holding the hostage, I'll immediately shout for him to surrender (Intimidation roll: 1d20+2=7).